# Using KDE activities to have different window layouts

Tags: kde, window-manager, plasma

Sorry if this is obvious, I am having a really hard time understanding exactly how I can use activities.

I have a workstation that I use in both a 1 monitor, 2 monitor, and 3 monitor set up, depending on where I am.

With KDE activities, is it possible to have 3 activities, say, "1 Screen", "2 Screens", "3 Screens" and set the positions of my windows in each of those activities? If so, how? From my experimentation, it looks like I'd have to have a separate instance of the application on each activity - which is not what I want.